# How can I restrict the members available in a dimension based upon the UserName function

Tags: ssas, mdx

Apologies - I'm not very Au Fait with MDX.

When browsing a cube I need a user to only be able to see certain members in a dimension, based on their User Name.

I have a dimension which includes the members for all Users, with the UserName as an attribute.
I would like to be able to filter out all members which are not related to the currently logged in user, but without restricting the fact data that the user has access to via other dimensions.

i.e. I don't want this to be a role security feature, because that would then restrict the fact rows that the user can see.

I just want to filter the members of a particular dimension based upon their UserName.

Comment: At face value it sounds like you'd want to use the Roles feature, except that you explicitly said you don't want to use that. :) Some questions that might assist with finding a solution: What is the purpose of filtering the dimension members if not to restrict the data the user has access to? And what client is the user using to browse the cube? Perhaps you can filter within the client application.

Comment: Thanks - I've revisited using a role and it does indeed seem to address the problem.